# How to get other row values for a max() value returned by a groupby

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm using the `max()` aggregator in a pandas `groupby` operation, and am wondering how I could possibly get other values returned from that row.

For example, take the following code:

```
df.groupby('occupation')['age'].max()
```

I get the following results:

[image]

What I'd like to do is get the user_id for the person in each occupation with the max value for age, but the following line just returns the highest value for user_id, not the user_id for the person with the max value for age:

```
df.groupby('occupation')[['user_id', 'age']].max()
```

These are the corresponding results:

[image]

If I do a mask like:

```
df[df.Age == 62]
```

There are no results returned that have a user_id for 922, so it's just pulling the highest value.

How do I get the user_id, or some other row value, for the row that has the highest max() value for a particular grouping?

Comment: Hey Jonathan, thanks for posting showing that output, could you also provide what `df` looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `idxmax`:

```
idx = df.groupby('occupation')['age'].idxmax()
```

and then the persons with max age:

```
df.loc[idx]
```

which gives you **one** person for each group. If you want **all** persons with max age, then use `transform`:

```
max_ages = df.groupby('occupation')['age'].transform('max')

df[df['age'].eq(max_ages)]
```